# Trouble installing parallels tools on ubuntu

Tags: installation

I've installed ubuntu on Win 8 parallels workstation extreme, however can't figure out how to install the parallels tools. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Parallels Tools from the 'Virtual Machine" menu of Parallels when the VM is running. However, some Linux distros do not play well with the installer and may require that you install them from the command line in the virtual machine. You may find [this article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/113394) helpful for installing from the command line.